# jquery variable if statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to pass a php variable in the form of destination IDs from a checkbox into my javascript that will trigger if the page loads more results or not.

By using the console.log and figuring out how to set up the variable I am able to pull the Destination IDS.

I am having trouble implementing the if else statement.. I have played around with the .val() and .length() but It does not seem to work.

I basicly want it to work something like `if(destination.length() < 1 ) {execute the jquery}` and if destination value is not empty or null then do nothing...

Here is my code! Thanks for taking the time to help.

```
Query(document).ready(function() {
    var is_loaded = true;
    var nextPage = 2 ;
    var destination = $("input[name='destinations[]']:checked").val() ;
    console.log(destination);
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(destination.length() < 1) {
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()) {
                jQuery('div#loadMore').show();
                if(is_loaded){
                    is_loaded = false;
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://www.pgtpackages.com/api_courselist.php?offset='+ nextPage +'&format=html',
                        success: function(html) {
                            console.log(html);
                            is_loaded = true;
                            nextPage++;
                            if(html){
                                jQuery("#infiscroll").append(html);
                                jQuery('div#loadMore').hide();
                            }else{
                                jQuery('div#loadMore').replaceWith("<center><h1  style='color:red'>End of Content !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }//DESTINATION.val
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Well does `console.log($("input[name='destinations[]']:checked"));` return anything?

Comment: so what is your requirement, to check if any one checkbox is selected????

Comment: You have an extra `});` at the end.

Comment: Yes. console.log(destination) returns the id of the destination that has been checked. My requirements is to check if any checkbox is selected and if so not to execute my lazy load. If nothing is seleceted to execute the loading

Comment: my answer below will do trick for you. Please try it and let me know in case you need further help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
var destination = $("input[name='destinations[]']:checked").val()
```

with

```
var destination = $("input[name='destinations[]']:checked").length;
```

and now `destination` will get you exact number of selected checkbox and you can use `if` on you `destination`,

Something like

```
if(destination<1){//run code}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the .length but with .length() instead... Thank you!